# Grabbing the vertices and indices from a Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, mesh

Is it possible to grab the indices/vertices from an XNA model object? I want to process the geometry for collision detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.roastedamoeba.com/blog/archive/2010/12/10/drawing-an-xna-model-bounding-box) recently on drawing a bounding box for an XNA model, and the source include includes a [VertexElementExtractor](https://github.com/roastedamoeba/xna-tutorials/blob/master/DrawBoundingBox/DrawBoundingBox/DrawBoundingBox/BoundingBoxes/VertexElementExtractor.cs) class which should do exactly what you want. Since it's short I'll include the code here:

```
public static class VertexElementExtractor
{
    public static Vector3[] GetVertexElement(ModelMeshPart meshPart, VertexElementUsage usage)
    {
        VertexDeclaration vd = meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration;
        VertexElement[] elements = vd.GetVertexElements();

        Func<VertexElement, bool> elementPredicate = ve => ve.VertexElementUsage == usage && ve.VertexElementFormat == VertexElementFormat.Vector3;
        if (!elements.Any(elementPredicate))
            return null;

        VertexElement element = elements.First(elementPredicate);

        Vector3[] vertexData = new Vector3[meshPart.NumVertices];
        meshPart.VertexBuffer.GetData((meshPart.VertexOffset * vd.VertexStride) + element.Offset,
            vertexData, 0, vertexData.Length, vd.VertexStride);

        return vertexData;
    }
}
```

If possible, however, I recommend extracting the vertices at build-time, using the XNA Content Pipeline. The [Picking with Triangle Accuracy](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/picking_triangle) sample on App Hub does this.